# Tables structure for shop - items - prices

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Suppose I have 15 shops, 4 products and custom prices for each shop:

- each shop doesn't have all the 4 products but can have only 2, or 3 or 4 or even 1.
- the prices are similar but customized to each shop. The prices change every 2-3 weeks in all shops, often simultaneously but not always.
- the database must contain the historical of the prices.

This is my idea but I'm sure it lacks in the products section:

```
TABLE1

id | shop_name | product_1 | product_2 | product_3 | product_4
1    shop1       name2       name4       NULL        NULL
2    shop2       name1       name3       name4       NULL

TABLE2
id | shop_name | active_from | active_to | name1 | name2 | name3 | name4
1    shop1       2014-01-05    2014-02-07  NULL    price   NULL    price
2    shop2       2014-01-07    2014-02-05  price   NULL    price   price
3    shop2       2014-02-06    NULL        price   NULL    price   price
4    shop1       2014-02-08    NULL        NULL    price   NULL    price
```

To get the data of the current prices I could select the rows `where active_to is NULL` and `JOIN` the tables to connect table1 with table 2.

To create an istorical chart or table I'll use the `between active_from and active_to` method.

But I'm limited to 4 products, what if they increase in the future?

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

A table that contains the presence of each product in each shop and its price.

```
    shop_id | product_id | price
          1 |          1 |  10.23
          1 |          2 |  13.51
          1 |          3 | 324.12
          2 |          1 |  13.20
          2 |          3 |   9.80
```

In this example you see that shop 1 sells products 1, 2 and 3, while shop 2 sells products 1 and 3 only. This is the simple way to do it. It would be better, maybe, to use a table for storing which products are sold in which shops and another table for the prices, since they are different concepts.

Then another table for storing all the changes that have been made to the prices. With this table you can trace back all the price history.

```
shop_id | product_id | date
      1 |          1 | 10.23
      1 |          1 | 10.08
    ... |        ... |  ...
```

Whatever solution you take, **do not create a column for each product** unless you have some strange and very strong reason to do it.